# How to enforce the declaration of parameters and return types in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently setuping some kind of big project in angular, that will be under development for the next year with a team of multiple individuals.

I would like to enforce that every method should absolutely defines the types of its parameters and the type of its return.

We are using Eslint with prettier. Is there a way to enforce this? Or at least mark it as a warning/error in the editor.

Ideally I would like to fix it automatically on format, but the minimum would be that the linting prevents it.

Is this something possible?

Comment: using 'sttrict' will force developers to add proper types to arguments and returned values. is there a reason you're not using that?

Comment: Are you talking about the `compilerOptions: { "strict":true}` of the tsconfig.json? Because it is set to true, but still, nothing prevents me of doing: `doSomething() {   return "something";  }`